# Total tax burden on the average American and how has it changed over the years

Tags: united-states, history, taxes

It is easy to find information on the average amount Americans pay in Federal taxes. It is little more difficult to find out state and local taxes. But we also have a plethora of other taxes, property taxes, sales taxes, and so on. We pay taxes to register our vehicles on the gas to fuel them. We pay taxes on our phone bills and other utilities.

Many localities have special taxes on hotels, restaurants, and car rentals. The concept being those taxes are more apt to be paid by visitors instead of residents that elect the officials that impose the tax.

New taxes seem to be invented every few years. As electric vehicles become more prevalent and they no longer pay gas taxes, several states want to impose a mileage tax on all vehicles.

Those of us that rent pay the property taxes on the units, but indirectly. We pay rent to the property owner, but the actual tax money comes out of our rent.

When you tax businesses, the cost of the tax is past on to the consumers. in most cases a business that has a 30% profit margin get a 5% tax increase, they seldom keep the prices the same and accept a lower profit margin, they raise their prices to keep the same profit margin.

I have heard that in the last 50 year the tax burden has approximately doubled.

However I cannot find any actual statistics on how high the tax burden is and on how much it has increased. Are there any reliable and relatively complete data set available?

Comment: Taxes are on business profits (revenue - costs). There isn't anything to "pass on to the consumers". If a business has less revenue than costs, then they don't pay any taxes.

Comment: @uberhaxed Economists are all over the map on the economic incidence of business profits.

Comment: It's true though that company profit tax increases aren't the same as cost increases to a business. In a stable high competition environment, companies have theoretically already been forced to find the price that gives them the highest **total** profit (which is dependent on market share as well as profit margin; the profit tax rate doesn't affect the profit margin, it determines what percentage of the total profit they get to keep). If they increase from that price they lose market share and their *total* profit will drop, not rise, so it won't actually cover for the tax rise after all.

Comment: Of course in the modern economy we have a *lot* of companies that have a monopoly-ish position. If there are 100 pencil sellers, pencils are fairly interchangeable so I can switch my supplier if one of them increases their prices; everyone knows that which actually stops them raising their prices in the first place. But although Netflix is in competition with Stan, their products aren't interchangeable (unless I just want to watch TV without caring *what* I watch). If Netflix puts their prices up switching vendors doesn't get me the same value. There are a lot of markets like that these days.

Comment: It's easy to measure income tax from a payroll, but when products or services are sold by the state it's almost impossible to separate taxes from fees for products and services. Fees often have a component that covers the cost of administration and associated costs, but also an element of "profit" or tax that goes to government. Even something like parking fees or road tolls may partly cover the costs of provision but include a penalty element that goes into local government coffers and is intended to discourage polluting vehicles (while providing an incentive for less polluting vehicles).

Comment: You have not been around long, or paying attention at all, if you believe that today we pay anything like the amount of taxes paid 50 years ago (in the US at least). Taxes have been cut relentlessly, and everything from education to infrastructure has suffered because of it. We have more disposable income, and a crumbling country today. The reason prices are higher is because the rich control the means of production, housing, raw materials, and government, and the rich want more and more, and they have been winning for years.

Comment: "I have heard that in the last 50 year the tax burden has approximately doubled." Citation needed. Honestly, it would be interesting to know who is saying that.

Comment: @Ben In a static situation you are right, companies can't pass on costs.  However, the real world isn't static.  When profits are high companies expand or new companies are created to take advantage of this.  When profits are low companies that fail don't get replaced.  The result is in any non-monopoly market prices will eventually settle at a reasonable profit margin.  Thus, in the end taxes will be passed on.

Answer (score 33):

#### Short Answer

> I have heard that in the last 50 year the tax burden has approximately
> doubled.

This has certainly not been the case as a percentage of income.

This is also not true as a percentage of GDP. [Nominal GDP](https://healthy.kaiserpermanente.org/html/kaiser/index.shtml) has increased by 23-fold from 1970 to 2023, but a lot of that is simply due to inflation. [Inflation adjusted GDP](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/GDPC1) has increased by 4-fold from 1970 to 2023.

So, the actual inflation adjusted tax collections have increased by more than double in the last fifty years, but the burden as a percentage of income has not doubled in the last fifty years.

#### Total Tax Collections In The U.S. Over Time

This table from official government statistics via Wikipedia shows combined federal, state, and local tax collections from all sources in the U.S. as a percentage of GDP from the years 1792 to 2016.

[image]

([Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Federal,_state,_and_local_tax_revenue_as_a_percent_of_GDP.pdf))

The same data from about 1950 from the St. Louis regional office of the Federal Reserve (at the same source) is as follows (note that the chart does not show the full range of possible values down to zero which makes it look more variable than it actually is):

[image]

Basically the same information (as a share of national income rather than GDP which are subtly different) from 1902 to 1992 in a prettier chart:

[image]

([Source](https://ourworldindata.org/taxation))

The totals per the St. Louis Fed for state and local taxes only (not adjusted for inflation or GDP) since 1992 are:

[image]

([Source](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/QTAXTOTALQTAXCAT1USNO))

#### An International Comparison Over Time

An international comparison is [here](https://ourworldindata.org/taxation):

[image]

#### Breakdowns By Specific Types Of Taxes

At the federal level, the breakdown from the 1930s to 2009 by type of tax revenue is:

[image]

([Source](https://stats.areppim.com/stats/stats_usxreceipts.htm))

At the state and local level, the change in tax collections since 1998 by type of tax revenue is:

[image]

([Source](https://www.nasra.org/revenue))

#### Total Tax Burdens Over Time By Income Percentile

The *New York Times* in [an October 6, 2019 feature](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2019/10/06/opinion/income-tax-rate-wealthy.html) had a dynamic chart showing the total combined federal, state and local tax burden by income percentile from 1950 to the most recent available data.

In 1950, the median taxpayer paid an average of about 18% of their income in combined federal, state, and local taxes, while the rate for the top 400 taxpayers was about 70%.  It looked like this:

[image]

In 1974, the tax burden looked like this and was about 30% for the median taxpayer and 56% for the top 400 taxpayers:

[image]

By the year 2018 (the last year for which data was available at the time), the tax burden looked like this and was about 26% for a median taxpayer and 22% for the top 400 taxpayers:

[image]

Thus, the total federal, state and local combined tax burdens on both the median taxpayer and the top 400 taxpayers has fallen in the last fifty years as a percentage of income.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147501/discussion-on-answer-by-ohwilleke-total-tax-burden-on-the-average-american-and-h); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.